# VSCodeのVisual Studio Code RemoteExtension機能使用時にsettings.jsonの内容をリモート環境用に切り替えたい

Tags: vscode

いつもお世話になっております。

VSCodeの`Visual Studio Code Remote` Extension使用時に
settings.jsonの内容がリモート環境用に自動的に切り替わるようにしたいのですが
どうすればできますか？

### 経緯

- クライアントPC(Windows)からリモートサーバー(Linux)にVSCodeのリモート機能で接続
- リモートサーバーにクライアントと同じExtensionをインストール

  - Java Extension PackなどJava開発に必要なExtension
- インストール後、プラグインが発狂
- プラグインが参照している `settings.json` がクライアントPCのものを参照しており、
  クライアントで作業するために入れていた設定値を読み込もうとしていたためとわかる
- リモートサーバーに接続していないときは上記設定値を使いたいので、リモートサーバーとクライアント用の設定を併存したい

```js
//一例...パスがWindowsのまま
{
    "vs-kubernetes": {
        "vs-kubernetes.minikube-path": "C:\\Users\\admin\\.vs-kubernetes\\tools\\minikube\\windows-amd64\\minikube.exe"
    },
    "java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-11.0.3.7-hotspot"
}
```

### とりあえずの対策

- リモートサーバーの~パス配下にworkspace用の設定ファイルを格納してそれを読み込むことで上記問題に対応しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リモートで接続した場合、初期状態ですと仰られた通り
クライアント環境のsettings.jsonを読み込んでしまいます。

ですので、接続後にコマンドパレット（F1）を開いて
「preferences: open remote settings」を編集する必要があります。
初期状態は、一切何も記載されていない状態ですので、ホスト環境のsettings.jsonをコピペすればOKです。